# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v see invocation) Xcode error

Tags: xcode, react-native, maps

I am trying to get google maps to work on react native app and have since got the iOS maps working, but not this. My preprocessor macros has "HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1" already.

Here is a warning above the Xcode error

```
   Showing Recent Issues
    :-1: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kentonpalmer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pollen7-gosfivqbporafncxmkhpomwwyqqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'

ld: 142 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `pod install` or `pod update`? Had an similar issue, caused of that I forgot to run pod install after upgrading some components.

I recommend to `clean` Build before re-run the Packager.